# Any known add-ins that increase IE Execution Speed?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11, add-in, watir-webdriver

My team is using Ruby Watir Webdriver to create automation scripts for our applications. IE11 is our browser that we must script to. We have noticed that our same script runs 30% faster in Firefox than it does in IE. This difference is speed, affects our script's ability to "see" elements fast enough. Are there any add-ins that increase IE's speed? We are using IEDriverServer version 2.48.0

Answer (score 0):

Surely 30% is a tolerable difference between two completely different browsers? I'm very surprised the difference is so small.

As these posts from Jim Evans of Selenium show, working with the IE Driver hasn't always been easy:

- http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/screenshots-sendkeys-and-sixty-four.html
- http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/using-internet-explorer-webdriver.html
- http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/whats-wrong-with-internet-explorer.html

Perhaps this is a legitimate reason for upping the hardware spec for your IE test environment, so that the cost is mitigated. Or else concentrating your tests so that only the IE-specific ones need IE, while the uncontroversial bulk can run on faster environments.

Speed should never be allowed to influence test **reliability or variability**, but provided you are using proper waits, that shouldn't be an issue. It wouldn't be fair to blame the IE Driver for that.

I doubt that the use of any particular testing framework (Watir) will make too much difference.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I will review the 3 links above to see Jim Evans' opinion on this